# how to sort array based on value os child array

Tags: php, arrays

Below is my array , i want to sort it based on [attributes]->[0]->[value]
how can i do it please guide me.
i tried using sort but how to make it work for value of child array.
Pls guide me its new for me.

```
[549246] => Array
        (
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [price] => $281.00
                    [qty] => 10
                    [prod_id] => 549246
                )

            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => sizes
                            [label] => Size
                            [value] => 25mg
                            [attribute_id] => 191
                            [option_id] => 26
                        )

                )

        )

    [549245] => Array
        (
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [price] => $75.00
                    [qty] => 10
                    [prod_id] => 549245
                )

            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => sizes
                            [label] => Size
                            [value] => 5mg
                            [attribute_id] => 191
                            [option_id] => 24
                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below;

```
function customer_sort ($a, $b) {

if ((int)$a['attributes'][0]['value'] == (int)$b['attributes'][0]['value']) {
    return 0;
}

return (int)$a['attributes'][0]['value'] > (int)$b['attributes'][0]['value'] ? 1 : -1;

}
uasort($arr, 'customer_sort');
```